# Pyside (or PyQt) Global shortcuts

Tags: python, pyqt, keyboard-shortcuts, pyside

I am looking to create a shortcut for my application that will still look for input while my application does not have focus. QShortcut and QApplicationShortcut don't seem to do what I need.

This is what I have. I would like to be able to trigger `self.onplaybutton()` while a different application has focus.

```
self.shortcut = QtGui.QShortcut(self.mainWindow)
self.shortcut.setKey('A')
self.shortcut.activated.connect(lambda: self.onplaybutton())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, Qt doesn't provide an API for global shortcuts, so you can't do this directly with either PySide or PyQt.

Instead, you will have to use an external library, and the only thing available seems to be [libqxt](https://github.com/strixcode/libqxt), which has a [QxtGlobalShortcut](https://github.com/strixcode/libqxt/blob/master/src/widgets/qxtglobalshortcut.cpp) class.

Fortunately, the [pygs](https://github.com/jmatt/pygs) project provides a PyQt bindings for the `QxtGlobalShortcut` class, so that provides at least way to get what you want.

---

**UPDATE**:

For PyQt5 support, there's [PyQxtGlobalShortcut](https://github.com/frispete/PyQxtGlobalShortcut), which is a fork of `pygs`. This project hasn't been updated since 2016, but [libqxt](https://github.com/strixcode/libqxt) still seems to be actively maintained, so it probably could be brought up to date without too much difficulty. (PS: in fact, there's a more recent fork [here](https://github.com/pawelkoston/PyQxtGlobalShortcut)).