# QShortcuts in Pyqt5 which works even without focus on any window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

**Summary:**

I've created a `function` which on `trigger` will show a color picker, A `QAction()` which on `trigger` will run that `function`.
A `shortcut` is setup for that `QAction`, but clicking that shortcut **doesn't** work.

**Note:** I've put that QAction in the context menu of system tray.

**What I've tried:**

1.) I set a shortcut on QAction using `self.action.setShortcut(QSequence('Shift+BackSpace'))` Also with `self.action.setShortcut('Shift+BackSpace')`  **None Worked**

2.) I tried setting a `QShortcut` with proper syntax on my main window.   **Working only when that window has focus**

**Result (my founding & could be wrong):**

1.) For `shortcut` to work, that window must've focus.

2.) Since `QAction` is in system tray context menu, No window in focus, so shortcut won't work.

3.) I'm now confused, if setting a shortcut like this is even possible or not, so it would work even without any focus on the window.

4.) But there are many apps which shows such behaviour: Like they are running but they are not under focus, but still their shortcuts work. For Ex: PowerToys (by Microsoft)

**What my goal is:**

1.) A `QAction` in my system tray context menu, triggering which should open color picker **(Done using `trigger` signal)**

2.) A shortcut which should open color picker no matter if any window has focus or not *(untill my app is running)*    **(Need help)**

Comment: The short answer to your question is: no, in Qt there is *no* "global shortcut" that can be triggered from anywhere in the system. If you're on Windows, look for the win32 module, which I believe allows sytem-wide shortcuts.

Comment: There are (or were) some third-party libraries with python bindings that provide this functionality. See: [Pyside (or PyQt) Global shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22368695/984421).